# ImportError ошибка импорта внутри пакета

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Дано: Python 3.4 + успешно установленый в /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages модуль(pip3 install builders):

```
    ../builders/info.py
    ../builders/logger.py
    ../builders/modifiers.py
    ../builders/__init__.py
    ../builders/builder.py
    ../builders/construct.py
```

Не удается импортировать класс из модуля:

```
>>> from builders.builder import Builde
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/builders/builder.py", line 1, in <module>
    import construct
ImportError: No module named 'construct'
```

Почему ошибка импорта возникает внутри модуля(в **builder.py** импортируется **construct.py**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builders/builder.py` сломан на Python 3. Следует использовать либо абсолютный импорт (`from builders import construct`) или явный относительный импорт (`from . import construct`). Неявные относительные импорты (`import construct`) запрещены в Python 3 и были плохой практикой даже в Python 2.

Comment: На 3.4 все равно не взлетело, т.к. помимо неявного относительного импорта в модуле присутствует циклический импорт(circular import), такие импорты поддерживаются в 3.5, на 3.5 удалось библиотеку завести.